# XMPP - Many resources on one session?

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire

Is there any way (in OpenFire or ejabberd) to bind many resources to one xmpp session?

There was a proposal for this http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0193.html but now it's deprecated and i couldn't find any implementation of it.

sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

No, few servers support this feature. Jabberd2 does however, I believe.

For the record, I dropped this feature from Prosody very early on. I found it unnecessarily complicated things, and I couldn't really find any strong use cases where it would be necessary. I'm very curious as to your use case if you have one already.